# Query to get all the dataset in a project across all regions in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

`SELECT * FROM myproject.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`. This query only gives the datasets in US region but not EU or any other region is there a way/query to get all the datasets across all regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-datasets-schemata#scope_and_syntax)

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`

The above query will list the dataset in the region US by default.To get the list of dataset in a particular region you need to given region as mentioned in below query

`SELECT * FROM region-REGION.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`;

Example:

[image]

Based on my understanding you can't list all dataset across all region using query. For your requirement, you can consider using a client library to list all dataset  across the whole [region](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets#list_datasets). I have used python to list all the dataset which you can use as reference.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()


datasets = list(client.list_datasets())  # Make an API request.
project = client.project


if datasets:
   print("Datasets in project {}:".format(project))
   for dataset in datasets:
       print("\t{}".format(dataset.dataset_id))
else:
   print("{} project does not contain any datasets.".format(project))
```

Output:
[image]

For more information  you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets#sql).

Comment: Yes, i was not getting any row using the 
SELECT * FROM `gcp-proj.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`
Because everything is on EU region and it seems to look only on the default US region

just when i literally added the EU Region
SELECT * FROM `gcp-proj.region-EU.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`
it return the datasets i'm looking for,