# How to read all the datasets which are located in different regions from a specific project?

Tags: google-bigquery

In my project we are using `SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.5.0.1001` JDBC driver to communicate with Google BigQuery.  By using this JDBC driver I want to read all the datasets which are located in different regions in a project.

Example:

A "TestProject" has "Dataset_1" from the region 'US', "Dataset_2" from the region 'europe-west1', "Dataset_3" from the region 'asia-east2' and "Dataset_4" from the region 'asia-northeast1'.

While querying the datasets, I don't know about the dataset locations. But I want to read all the datasets along their information.

How to achieve this?

I tried using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`, but it requires region.

Comment: Hi @Srinivas B, Have you checked this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75625104/query-to-get-all-the-dataset-in-a-project-across-all-regions-in-big-query) ? Let me know if this is helpful for you or not ?

Comment: Hi @Srinivas B, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @kiran mathew in this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627807/18329678) , you can't list all dataset across all regions  using query. You can try using the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets#list_datasets) code for your requirement.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.